# Is mysql login path a secure way to access database without password ? Is there alternatives?

Tags: mysql, database, security, passwords

I have a question regarding the mysql login path functionality.

I'm looking for a way to host my databases on a server without having to type in the passwords every time I want to access one (which is quite frequent). 
In the same time, I do not want to let mysql open without any password or with a weak password like 'password' and the same user for all my projects : I have one user per database and one strong password per user.

That's why the mysql login path looked like a good solution : I can manage any number of users with their own password without having to type in the specific password every time.

But if I set up a login path configuration for those databases, every people on the host, with the good login path command could access the database, is it right ?

Is there a way to secure the login path with some kind of unique root/master password ? 
Or to make it functional only with the sudo command to avoid anybody accessing the databases ?

If it's not possible, is there an other way to keep databases secured (one user per database, one strong password per user) without having to type in the password for each every time I need to connect to one ?

Maybe that's a dumb question and I'm looking for something that does not exists...

Thanks!

Comment: What tool are you using to connect? MySQL Workbench will store passwords for you. Or maybe a password manager could do it for you.

Comment: I should have been more specific on this point but I'm connecting through the shell, I'm not using any program. I have a keepass to store my passwords but I don't wish to go in it anytime I need to connect to a database

Comment: Ok I see. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.html says "The file location is the %APPDATA%\MySQL directory on Windows and the current user's home directory on non-Windows systems". So unless security on your machine is so bad that people can see into each other's home directories then I can't see too much of a risk here - the login path file is specific to you as a user. In a normal set up no-one else should be able to access it.